# Explicit construction of equivariant map between arbitrary representation and Adjoint representation

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a compact (semi-simple) Lie group, $\rho :G\to \operatorname{Aut}\left( V \right)$ an arbitrary but orthogonal representation on the real vector space $V$ and $\operatorname{Ad}:G\to \operatorname{Aut}\left( \mathfrak{g} \right)$ the Adjoint representation, which can be considered orthogonal. Since compactness implies unimodularity, I found that the following linear map:
$$H:V\to \mathfrak{g}\quad ,\quad v\mapsto \int_{G}{d\mu \left( g \right)\left\langle \rho \left( g \right)v,{{\rho }_{*}}\left( {{\tau }_{r}} \right){{v}_{0}} \right\rangle \operatorname{Ad}\left( {{g}^{-1}} \right){{\tau }_{r}}}$$
is equivariant, i.e. $H\circ \rho \left( g \right)=\operatorname{Ad}\left( g \right)\circ H$ for any $g\in{G}$. In the above, $d\mu \left( g \right)$ is the Haar measure, $\left\langle \cdot .\cdot  \right\rangle :V\times V\to \mathbb{R}$ the scalar product of $V$, $\left\{ {{\tau }_{r}} \right\}$ an orthonormal basis of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $v_0\in{W}\subset{V}$, where $W$ is a topologically closed submanifold of $V$ which does not contain the zero vector and such that $G$ acts transitively on W. In particular:

1. $H$ it does not depend on the chosen orthonormal basis of $\mathfrak{g}$
2. the right-invariance of the Haar measure implies that $H$ is equivariant
3. the left-invariance of the Haar measure and the transitivity of $G\times{W}\to{W}$ imply that $H$ does not depend on the choice of $v_0\in{W}^{[1]}$

Is there a chance that this map is identically equal to zero? If not, is it surjective? If yes, are there any conditions on $\rho$ and/or $G$ such that it is non-trivial?

Is there a general procedure (as the above naive map) which can determine equivariant maps $V\to\mathfrak{g}$ ? If yes, under which conditions such maps are non-trivial?

---

[1] for the proof of 3. I made use of the identity $\rho \left( g \right){{\rho }_{*}}\left( X \right)\rho \left( {{g}^{-1}} \right)={{\rho }_{*}}\left( \operatorname{Ad}\left( g \right)X \right)$ which holds for any $g\in{G}$ and $X\in\mathfrak{g}$ and took into account that $\left\{\operatorname{Ad(g)}\tau_r\right\}$ is an orthonormal basis if {\tau_r} is.